# Frames per second meaning for object detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

How do you interpret "frames per second" when it comes to computer vision models?

If my model can analyze each test image in .50 seconds, does that mean it's 2 frames per second since it can analyze 2 images in one second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. At the end it only depends on where you use it. Online/offline, video or photo. The construct of frames per seconds processing speed (FPS) is a way to express how fast the method is. Often you can bump it to the term "real time" which is a way to express that the method can process a video sequence "online" with the asumption of the video having a frame rate of 25 (FPS). The term "real time" is often disliked, because in and of itself it does not state anything.